# How to select strong tag inside a link and change color on hover

Tags: css

I'm sure this is really easy, but I can't figure out how to do it, nor do I have the words to find help when I search.

I have a link. Some of the text inside the link is inside a `<strong>` tag. The `<strong>` text has a color. On hover the `<strong>` text isn't changing color. How do I get it to change color?

```
a:link {
  color: rgb(25, 50, 50);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: rgb(25, 50, 50);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(100, 200, 200);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  color: rgb(100, 200, 200);
  text-decoration: none;
}

strong {
  color: rgb(50, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
    <li><a href="xyz.html"><img src="resources/logo.jpg"><div class="list_text"><strong>Heading</strong><br>Sub heading</div></a></li>
```

I want the text inside the strong tag on hover and active to be the same color as the 'sub heading' text rgb(100,200,200).

Comment: You want the text in the strong tag to change when any part of the link is hovered, or only when the text in the strong tag is hovered?

Comment: I want all the text (inside and outside the strong tag) to change color on hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```css
a:link { color:rgb(25,50,50); text-decoration:none; }
a:visited { color:rgb(25,50,50); text-decoration:none; }
a:hover strong { color:rgb(100,200,200); text-decoration:none; }
a:hover { color:rgb(100,200,200); text-decoration:none; }
a:active { color:rgb(100,200,200); text-decoration:none; }

strong { color:rgb(50,100,100); }
```

```html
<a href="xyz.html"><strong>Heading</strong><br>Sub heading</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. But it still isn't working for me. I'm going to edit my question because the code is a little more complicated than the simplified version I've give above.

Comment: Sorry I made a simple mistake. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
a:hover {
  color: rgb(100, 200, 200);
}

a:hover strong {
  color: rgb(100, 200, 200);
}
```

or

```
a:hover, 
a:hover strong {
  color: rgb(100, 200, 200);
}
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/b0nrf70p/1/**

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your existing hover selector to include the strong element with `a:hover, a:hover > strong`

```css
a:link {
  color: rgb(25, 50, 50);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: rgb(25, 50, 50);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:hover > strong {
  color: rgb(100, 200, 200);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  color: rgb(100, 200, 200);
  text-decoration: none;
}

strong {
  color: rgb(50, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<a href="xyz.html"><strong>Heading</strong><br>Sub heading</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/Czeran/pen/zdZeGx

```
a>strong:hover {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Strong element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) have a contextual meaning and therefore it have default style in "browser user agent stylesheet" what have bigger weight in order.

Solution is use [Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) cascade design to define element and rewrite style. I used cascade path "a strong" and value "[inherit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp)" to get value from parent element.

Here is [preview](https://bgstudio.online/!shared/anchor-strong.html) and code:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a strong {
    color: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
    color: rgb(25, 50, 50);
}

a:hover,
a:active {
    color: rgb(100, 200, 200);
}

strong {
    color: rgb(50, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<a>anchor <strong>strong</strong></a>
```

I hope it help.